# Parsing specific data from a webpage

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am getting data from the [this webpage](http://www.flysat.com/turksat42.php) using following code block.
I think this code block is not reasonable because I used to bordercolor of table.
But I could not find different way to get data. Is there a different way because I am newbie in C#.

Thanks for your help.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@bordercolor='#3366cc']/tr"))
{
    sXPath = node.XPath + "/td[2]/font[1]";
    htmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(sXPath);

    if(htmlNode != null)
    {
        if (htmlNode.InnerText.Length >= 7)
        {
            string freq = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 5);
            if (int.TryParse(freq, out intFrequency) == true)
            {
                string pol = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(6, 1);
                if (pol == "H")
                    bPolarity = false;
                else if (pol == "V")
                    bPolarity = true;
            }
        }
    }

    sXPath = node.XPath + "/td[3]/font[1]";
    htmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(sXPath);

    if (htmlNode != null)
    {
        if (htmlNode.InnerText.Length >= 5)
        {
            string sr = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 5);
            if (int.TryParse(sr, out intSymbolRate) == false)
            {
                sr = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 4);
                int.TryParse(sr, out intSymbolRate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the colour of a table as your source is definitely fragile... there must be something else specific to the table you could query on? i.e. class name, id etc.?

Comment: I found it much easier using WebClient and then parsing the received string, instead of using a library that parses the HTML itself.

Comment: There is no class name, id etc. I couldn't find anything else except for bordercolor.

Comment: @user3319676 if you need to pull the data in at table level then yeah there isn't much information. Do you need the entire table information or can you maybe drill into just the section you need? Also, it might be worth getting in touch with the provider and asking if they surface some sort of API you can leverage. Regardless, if what you have works then just stick with it until it becomes a problem - if they change the style then there is a good chance your app will break, that's the downside.

Comment: @Vasil that's completely subjective, complex HTML parsing sometimes requires something a bit more sophisticated for querying - that's where tools like the HtmlAgilityPack really shine.

Comment: Thanks James that's what I want to hear.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using web client() or HTTP request for getting content from website which is much simpler

**Sample code:**

```
string winPhoneGeekTweetsUrl = @"http://sss.sss78.sset/wsss.php";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(winPhoneGeekTweetsUrl));
```

carry remaining function with `Downloadstringcompleted` event handler

Comment: I am using WebRequest to get content and htmlagilitypack to parse content. Could you please give me any example or link about WebClient? I have no idea about it. Is webclient like htmlagilitypack?

Comment: I need to get frequency, polarization and symbolrate values (Second and third columns).

Comment: I didn't understand your answer and sample. My problem is not to get content. My problem is to parse content with reasonable way.

Comment: Make the question to be clear, using reasonable way doesn't reach our mind. Reread your title again

Comment: Yes you are right. According to title your answer is acceptable, but i think my question and code block is clear. Using the colour of a table to get frequency value is not good way. There is no class name or id.I  am looking for different way.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. I understood the question, you clearly just didn't read it correctly or fully. It's pretty obvious that the issue is related to *parsing* and not *querying* the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found different way and i think this is better and stronger.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td/font"))
{
    if (node.InnerText == "Freq PolMode" || node.InnerText == "SR-FEC")
    {
        sXPath = node.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.XPath + "//tr";
        HtmlNodeCollection rows = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(sXPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sXPath = rows[i].XPath + "/td[2]/font[1]";
            htmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(sXPath);
            if (htmlNode != null)
            {
                if (htmlNode.InnerText.Length >= 7)
                {
                    string freq = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 5);
                    if (int.TryParse(freq, out intFrequency) == true)
                    {
                        string pol = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(6, 1);
                        if (pol == "H")
                            bPolarity = false;
                        else if (pol == "V")
                             bPolarity = true;
                     }
                 }
             }

             sXPath = rows[i].XPath + "/td[3]/font[1]";
             htmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(sXPath);
             if (htmlNode != null)
             {
                 if (htmlNode.InnerText.Length >= 5)
                 {
                     string sr = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 5);
                     if (int.TryParse(sr, out intSymbolRate) == false)
                     {
                         sr = htmlNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 4);
                         int.TryParse(sr, out intSymbolRate);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         break;
     }
 }
```